# Pass parameters to Flask application using Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, url-parameters

I've looked at a handful of examples and tutorials, and as far as I can tell I have this correct.  With the basic example below I get the following error:  `TypeError: view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

location_app = Blueprint('location_app', __name__)

@location_app.route('/location/', defaults={'id': '0'})
@location_app.route('/location/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def view():
    return "location view"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function have to take the variable of the url definition. Like this:

```
@location_app.route('/location/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def view(id):
    return "location view"
```

Comment: It's always something simple.  Thank you.